# How to create a DSN file for an Access Database

Tags: ms-access, dsn

I've created an activity logger in Access which will be used by people in a different site.

In one I built previously it also had a DSN file to enable the second site users to use it, but I can't for the life of me remember how you go about creating one of these.

Could someone please run me through how it is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Windows 10, search for "ODBC Data Sources" and choose the 32-bit version. You can then choose System and File DSNs.

Comment: Thanks ThunderFrame - much appreciate